# Use Note field in Bibtex with CMS via Pandoc

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc

I'm super confused with BibTeX by now. I am using pandoc-citeproc to generate my PDFs from Markdown and everything works fine, except that the `note` field doesn't show up. I want to keep using pandoc-citeproc's CMS style, since it even supports `origdate` which I need. But I also need it to show the `note` field. I guess I will have to create a custom CSL file for that? So I need to create a modified [chicago-author-date.csl](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/blob/master/chicago-author-date.csl) I guess, but I don't know how to add the note field at all.

Comment: Can you come up with something illustrating your problem, like a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? I'm not entirely sure how a Pandoc MWE would look like, but I still think it could help us investigate the problem. I have re-tagged your question since it isn't about the LaTeX package `biblatex`, but Pandoc's citation handling.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got an answer on GitHub and figured it out. See own answer. The documentation for GLS and pandoc-citeproc is really confusing sadly. Still not sure how BibTeX fields are translated to CLS variables

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic, because this is not a tex problem. Pandoc and its cls styles don't use bibtex or biber. They hard code the bibliography as text at the end of the tex file. To change the appearance, intervention needs to happen before the tex file is even generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a hint [on github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/180#issuecomment-145912887) and figured it out. Simply add `<text variable="note" prefix=". "/>` right after `<text macro="access" prefix=". "/>.` in your own copy of the CLS file and use it with the `cls: your-styles.cls`